# Вращение 2D объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть 2D объект, который вращается, однако он должен прекратить вращение при повороте на 90 градусов. Проблема в том что он вращается беспрерывно.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class moveleft : MonoBehaviour
{
 private RectTransform rec1;

void Start()
{
    rec1 = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
} 
public void Update()
{
    if(rec1.rotation.y !=90)
    {
        rec1.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 1, 0));
    }
}
```

Мне нужно задать вращение через именно скрипт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите [документацию](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html) по `Transform.rotation` (то же справедливо и для `RectTransform`), это свойство возвращает `Quaternion`, а вы судя по всему, хотите ограничить вращение по углам Эйлера. Для того, чтобы получить вращение объекта в формате углов Эйлера воспользуйтесь [Quaternion.eulerAngles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-eulerAngles.html), то есть, например, замените в коде:`rec1.rotation.y` на `rec1.rotation.eulerAngles.y`